# How to do a negative regexp in Komodo editor search?

Tags: html, regex

I have 40 html pages. all this html pages contains a number of classes and ids. My client wants to prefix the class and ids like this: "z_classname", "#z_id" with all ids and classes throughout the 40 html pages.

Now I did this all by manually. I want to check the ids and classes where I am not prefixed. For that I like to use the regexp using my komodo editor find option. Komodo editor has the regexp support with find option. Anyone can help me how I can make the regexp to find the class and id's which is not contain the prefix "z_" ?

Comment: I don't understand your exact requirements. Could you edit your post and show some before/after examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if Komodo's regex engine supports [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), but if it does, then

```
(class|id)="(?!z_)([^"]*)"
```

should work.

Replace that with

```
\1="z_\2"
```

or possibly

```
$1="z_$2"
```

(again, depending on the implementation details of the Komodo regex library).

Answer (score 0):

class[=][^z][^_]

id[=][^z][^_]

Comment: it is finding the classes and ids where i have prefixed. i need to find where i am not. because that could be very less place. my work will finish easy

Comment: simply i say, whaterver classes and id's is not start with 'z_' i need to find.

Comment: adding ! should do it, but not sure of the syntax ...[=][!^z_]

Comment: class[=]["][^z][_] <- This is the correct one.

it checks the first two characters if they are not z_